# Java lambda not working with full definition

Tags: java, exception, lambda, java-8

I am trying to wrap methods which throws checked exceptions.. I am following steps told in this url: https://www.rainerhahnekamp.com/en/ignoring-exceptions-in-java/

Interestingly when I write the code like this:

```
IntStream.range(1, locales.length)
            .mapToObj(i -> locales[i].toString())
            .forEach(wrap(this::testLocale));
```

it is working fine but when I write like this:

```
IntStream.range(1, locales.length)
            .mapToObj(i -> locales[i].toString())
            .forEach(s -> wrap(testLocale(s)));
```

Intellij is complaining "Unhandled Exception: java.lang.Exception"

here testLocale looks like this:

```
void testLocale(String s) throws Exception
```

The wrap function looks like this:

```
public static <T> Consumer<T> wrap(WrapConsumer<T> wrapper) {
    return t -> {
        try {
            wrapper.accept(t);
        } catch(Exception exception) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exception);
        }
    };
}
```

and WrapConsumer is a function interface with Consumer signature:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface WrapConsumer<T> {
   void accept(T t) throws Exception;
}
```

I am banging my head trying to understand why Intellij is complaining based on how I write the lambda

Comment: `.forEach(wrap(s -> testLocale(s)))`. You have to wrap the consumer, not the method call. Note further, that you can use `Arrays.stream(locales, 1, locales.length) .map(Object::toString) .forEach(wrap(this::testLocale))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are supposed to provide a wrapped consumer to `forEach` via:

```
.forEach(wrap(this::testLocale));
```

what you are doing via `s -> wrap(testLocale(s))` is provide a *new* consumer that still can't handle the checked Exception.

Probably simpler to understand would be that `forEach` accepts a `Consumer` that has a method definition of:

```
void accept(T t); // does not define to throw the checked Exception
```

When you do `forEach(s -> ...)`, it is this `Consumer::accept` that you are using.

On the other hand that `forEach(wrap(this::testLocale));` will return a `Consumer` still, but by accepting as input a `WrapConsumer<T> wrapper` that *does* declare to throw that `Exception` via:

```
void accept(T t) throws Exception;
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick clarification

Answer (score 2):

You're just missing the correct lambda syntax. Your current code is calling  `wrap` with a `void` argument: `wrap(testLocale(s))` - (`testLocale(s)` has a void return type)

The correct lambda expression that you need is:

```
.forEach(wrap(s -> testLocale(s)));
```

`wrap` returns a function, so you don't need delayed execution for it (i.e., no need for a function that calls `wrap`).

Answer (score 2):

Just complementing what Eugene answered, you are expecting with the method wrap() a consumer as param, not a invocation method returning void.

You can prove this by removing the throws Exception from the testLocale method.

The IDE will them give you the error:

```
"reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that void conforms to WrapConsumer<T>"
```

The similar code for the one you wrote (right consumer):

```
IntStream.range(1, locales.length)
        .mapToObj(i -> locales[i].toString())
        .forEach(wrap(this::testLocale));
```

Would be:

```
IntStream.range(1, locales.length)
        .mapToObj(i -> locales[i].toString())
        .forEach(wrap(l-> testLocale(l)));
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation